# R: ggplot bar: display values sorted, for the values from a column determined by variable's value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In following code segment, in order to plot data as bar chart with values in decreasing order with ggplot,
I need to do transformation with a data.frame for a column to re-arrange the order of the column as factor.
The column name is not a constant, but is determined by value of an input variable, `feature.name`

I'm stucked at the place of expressing the tag for the column to
rearrange its order as factor: `feature.column`

When I called the function:

```
composite.analysis("product_group", "Winning_Feature", data,
                   "winning", "Winning Feature Popularity",
                   popularity_data)
```

I got no apparent error, but the bar
chart's values are not in proper order. Upon examination, I found that a new column was introduced, named `"feature.column"`. It seems that the column named `"winning"`
in this case didn't get factors re-ordered.

```
composite.analysis <- function(simple.var.str, complex.var.str, data, feature.name, feature.ranking.title, 
                               simple.order) {
  # Assume simple.var.str and complex.var.str are passed as strings
    to.study <- select(data, one_of(simple.var.str, complex.var.str))

    # split.vertically returns a new data frame having a column with
    # name as the value of the variable feature.name
  splitted <- split.vertically(to.study, feature.name)

  (eval(substitute(
    {
      # Compute the ranking of feature
      freq <- xtabs(frequency~feature.column, data = splitted)
      freq.sorted <- as.data.frame(freq) %>% arrange(Freq)
      freq.sorted <- transform(freq.sorted, feature.column = factor(feature.column, levels = freq.sorted[, feature.name]))
      #freq.sorted <- data.frame(factor(freq.sorted[, feature.name], levels = freq.sorted[, feature.name]), freq.sorted$Freq)
      rank.p <- ggplot(freq.sorted, aes(feature.column, Freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+ coord_flip() + ggtitle(feature.ranking.title)
      }, list(feature.column = as.name(feature.name)))))
  result <- list(freq.rank = rank.p, freq.sorted = freq.sorted)
  return(result)
  }
```

I also tried to rebuild a new data.frame with the the
column's factor re-ordered, (as the commented out line below the line of transform)
but when I called the function:

```
 composite.analysis("product_group", "Winning_Feature", data, "winning", "Winning Feature Popularity", popularity_data)
```

I got the error:

```
$freq.rank
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'winning' not found
```

I'm happy with whatever way to create the bar chart with values in
decreasing order. My current approach is just ad hoc, learning from
web.

Sorry, that I could not simplify my example enough, as
I'm having hard time to decide if I'm doing it properly with the
overall design, that I might make it unnecessarily hard.

Within my current design, in a nutshell,
I'd like to learn to do the following:

```
do.transform.by.variable <- function(df, column.to.change) {
return(transform(df, <some_way_to_represent_column.to.change and changes to it>)
}
```

Overall, I find R's language model intriguing. On the web, there are
many material on how easy it is to do near manual data processing, but I
found it hard to figure out how to do more generic programming, or
refactor repetitive manual operations into higher level abstraction.

I wish a furthre pointer to understand
R's language model to appreciate the nuance that I might not be aware.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that worked for me requirement:

```
        composite.analysis <- function(simple.var.str, complex.var.str, data, feature.name, feature.ranking.title, 
                                   simple.order) {
      # Assume simple.var.str and complex.var.str are passed as strings
        to.study <- select(data, one_of(simple.var.str, complex.var.str))

        # split.vertically returns a new data frame having a column with
        # name as the value of the variable feature.name
      splitted <- split.vertically(to.study, feature.name)

      (eval(substitute(
        {
          # Compute the ranking of feature
          freq <- xtabs(frequency~feature.column, data = splitted)
          freq.sorted <- as.data.frame(freq) %>% arrange(Freq)
          # not working this one: freq.sorted <- transform(freq.sorted, feature.column = factor(feature.column, levels = freq.sorted[, feature.name]))
          freq.sorted <- data.frame(factor(freq.sorted[, feature.name], levels = freq.sorted[, feature.name]), freq.sorted$Freq)
          # add the following make it work
          colnames(freq.sorted) <- c(feature.name, "Freq")
          rank.p <- ggplot(freq.sorted, aes(feature.column, Freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+ coord_flip() + ggtitle(feature.ranking.title)
          }, list(feature.column = as.name(feature.name)))))
      result <- list(freq.rank = rank.p, freq.sorted = freq.sorted)
      return(result)
      }
```

The alternative of constructing, instead of transformation, allows me to specify colname by variable of string!

Wish there is more consistent approach.